# Поле select и база данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть поле select (поле выбора) и значение этого поля необходимо внести в базу данных MySQL.

```
<select name="select5" id="select">
<option>Москва</option>
<option>Московская обл.</option>
<option>Санкт-Петербург</option>
<option>Астрахань</option>
<option>Владимир</option>
<option>Воронеж</option>
<option>Екатеринбург</option>
<option>Краснодар</option>
<option>Красноярск</option>
<option>Липецк</option>
<option>Ростов-на-Дону</option>
<option>Рязань</option>
<option>Самара</option>
<option>Саратов</option>
<option>Сочи</option>
</select>
```

после этого в исполняющем скрипте заношу в переменную значение этого поля

```
$select = $_POST['select5'];
```

Далее заношу данные в базу данных

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,select) 
VALUES('$login','$password','$select')");
```

после проверяю значение переменной result2, если да то перехожу на главную если нет выдает ошибку. Мне выдает ошибку. В чем я ошибся? С логином и паролем все норм.

Comment: ктонибудь объясните как здесь подсвечивать текст! Четыре пробела перед фрагментом кода никакого результата не дают

Comment: @LordyGL 3 правки и в пустую, зачем правишь тогда?

Comment: Как вариант, поле в таблеце с обозначением select использовать нельзя!

Comment: Нет конечно, не нормально! Запрос INSERT INTO ценит select как вторичный запрос к базе для получения тех или иных данных для занесеия куда то туда для чего собственно и был вызван запрос! думаю внятно объяснил, я не мастер в теории, я на практике больше)

Comment: а как занести русское слово в базу? например Москва

Comment: тю та обчно же! конкретно в БД select переименовать нужно!

Comment: Да уже давно переименовал. Проблема в другом. В поле слово русское МОСКВА в базу заносится как какаято абракадабра

Comment: Кодировку смотри!

Comment: Помоги я так не пойму о чем речь идет)

Comment: @LordyGL, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option>Московская обл.</option>
```

и что реально передается **Московская обл.**

т.е. без **value="блаблабла"**?

представляю программиста который после тебя будет смотреть код и не понимать откуда там что и где берется.

Думаю правила написания кода должны присутствовать в коде! Иначе это не код.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 1):

`'$login','$password','$select'` в одинарных кавычках переменная не подставляется, надо как-то так: `'.$login.'`